# ～まくる as a suffix, what does it mean and how is it used?

Tags: vocabulary, suffixes

I found this phrase 「家族に突っ込まれまくった」 and I believe it means "[my] family really stuck it [to me]" but I'm not familiar with the suffix まくる.

Any examples and clarifications would be appreciated.

Comment: [EDICT](http://jisho.org/words?jap=makuru&eng=&dict=edict) says "verb suffix to indicate reckless abandon to the activity."  Did you want additional information besides a definition?  If so, please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: @Amanda: Yup, I should've looked for the suffix by itself, but I wanted to get feel for its usage. I guess beyond the examples from @Axioplase there is not much more to it. Thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, first, I *think* your sentence translates as "my family put me in a very bad situation." If that's what you meant, forgive my bad English.

Then, for "まくる", a quick glance at ALC gave me nice examples to share with you:

～に長々としゃべりまくる: talk ~ to death
～のことであせりまくる: panic wildly about
～をしゃべりまくる: blat
(人）についてペラペラしゃべりまくる: gush over
エラーを出しまくる: give someone a bunch of errors (a program would)

I guess this is helps you understand the nuance of まくる.