# What does らいたい mean here?

Tags: meaning, manga

This is in the beginning of the Oregairu manga (it's on the 10th page of volume 1, which is in the free sample on [ebookjapan](http://www.ebookjapan.jp/ebj/175031/volume1/)):

> 近頃の高校生は**らいたい**こんな感じじゃないでしゅか

What does らいたい mean here?  I would also be interested in how I could have found the answer on the internet, since I couldn't find anything useful via various searches on google and jisho.

Comment: It's slurred 「だいたい」... and the 「でしゅか」 at the end is slurred 「ですか」(have no idea how to search these things on the Internet though..)

Comment: @chocolate Since your [comment answers the question](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/593/542), why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @Flaw すいません・・　「how I could have found the answer on the internet」ってとこに答えられなかったもので。。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you notice the same guy said 噛み[まくった](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1397/5010) in the next frame? Here 噛む is a slangy expression meaning "to falter" (see the [fifth definition in jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%99%9B%E3%82%80)).

The original sentence is: **だ**いたいこんな感じじゃないで**す**か.